# Remove array field if empty

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Please suggest how to remove array field if empty? I have tried below config :

```
if [tags] == [] {
mutate {
remove_field => ["tags"]
}
}

But getting logstash exception:
[2018-03-01T15:07:56,000][FATAL][logstash.runner ] The given configuration is invalid. Reason: Failed to parse right-hand side of conditional [str]pipeline:31:8:[tags] == []
```

Comment: i need this in logstash. link suggests to do in elasticsearch. pls suggest

Comment: I think you'll have to use the ruby filter, I haven't seen a way to do it otherwise.

Comment: with ruby code i am not able to check if array is empty and delete it. if found a method empty? in ruby but not working with logstash ruby filter. pls help with ruby code snippet any.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't know how to remove a field from inside the ruby filter, so when the `tags` array is empty, I'm setting another field and using to know when to remove the field `tags`.

```
ruby {
    code => "event.set('[is_tags_empty]', 'true') if event.get('[tags]').length == 0"
}

if [is_tags_empty] {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["tags","is_tags_empty"]
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked..! thanks alot. :)

whats event.set  event.get over here ? i think its pure ruby program wrapped with double quotes inside code block of ruby filter. am i correct?

Comment: This `event.set('[is_tags_empty]', 'true') if event.get('[tags]').length == 0` is the ruby program. `event.get('[tags]')` retrieve the field `tags` from the event, `event.set('[is_tags_empty]', 'true')` set the field `is_tags_empty` in the event to the value `true`.

Comment: For more information about the event, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Check for not null and if array is empty

```
if [tags] and !([tags][0]) {
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["tags"]
    }
}
```

Tested on Logstash 7.1

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
ruby {
  code => "if event.get('tags').length == 0 then event.remove('tags') end"
}
```